# Make m.me links open in specific language

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there any way to force the locale on an m.me link for facebook messenger. I was writing a web widget for client websites that would take their customers to their messenger page. Its for websites in UAE, so the link opens in Arabic for all customers, but most of the customers are non-Arab. Is there any way for me to set the a locale as a query param or something, so that the links will be always open in english?

Eg : `https://m.me/mypage?locale=en_US` will always open messenger.com in English.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the ref parameter to pass the locale in to your bot. You would store this value in a database, then use it to determine the language of future responses.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links

https://m.me/mybot?ref=en_US